# My Android App crashes after adding an OnclickListener

Tags: java, android

I tried to build an easy Android App using Java and, obviously, Android studio. After adding an OnClickListener the app keeps crashing on the emulator.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText first = findViewById(R.id.firstInput);
    EditText second = findViewById(R.id.secondInput);
    EditText result = findViewById(R.id.result);
    private Button add;

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            clicked();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        add = new Button(this);
        add.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        };

    void clicked(){
        int i = Integer.parseInt(first.getText().toString());
        int z = Integer.parseInt(second.getText().toString());

        int r = i + z;

        result.setText(r);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Wrong location of object declaration

It should be below the setContentView

```
    EditText first = findViewById(R.id.firstInput);
    EditText second = findViewById(R.id.secondInput);
    EditText result = findViewById(R.id.result);
```

2. Button haven't added to the layout

```
    add = new Button(this);
    addContentView(add, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Note: This is impractical, you should have added this on your layout xml unless you wanted to create dynamic layout

3. Warning issue of setting a text by integer

From:

```
    result.setText(r);
```

To:

```
    result.setText(String.valueOf(r));
```